# Web Server for testing on Linux

Tags: linux, testing

I am looking for a simple easy to use lightweight Web server ( linux/Ubuntu Koala ) for testing some web apps.

On Windows I used Web Savant ( which was rather easy, just enter the html directory and the bin directory and press start ) to give some people an idea of what I'm looking for.

**Update**: 
My apologies. I didn't realise that this was a requirement untill now.
Ideally the whole package would be one executable file, however since it is a webserver it would be understandable if there were some infrastructure created so maybe a tarball containing a executable. It would be nice if it started from the commandline and required no administrator privileges to run. Furthermore it should not require any configuration files or log files stored in any areas which are usually administrator access only.

PS This is a question about a tool for testing programs, not a question about system administration. Thus this question is appropriate for stackoverflow *not* serverfault. 
If you insist on arguing this, then I suggest you reread the question. Still want to argue?
Keep rereading the question untill you understand it, I'll wait. Understand it now? Good now go away.

Comment: Why not grab virtualbox http://www.virtualbox.org and run linux/ubuntu Koala from it? There should be apache/php among the ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @tommieb75: another idea: why not grab virtualbox from virtualbox.org and run windows from it?

Comment: @ChristopheD: true...even better, run windows 3.1!!!! :)

Comment: Could be interesting to complete your request: you need database ? Which technology do you want ? server-side: PHP, JSP Ruby ? client-side: Javascript, CSS, HTML ? hence the reply will be more adapted to your question...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-accepting-get-post-requests

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use CGI or plain HTML pages only, the simplest would be `thttpd` just:

```
thttpd -D -C '*.cgi' -p 8080
```

And go!

Lighttpd is very simple to configure as well, but requires writing a little configuration file.

Comment: +1 for the lighthttpd recommendation, this seems appropriate for this context

Comment: Thank you for being the only person answering who actually paid attention to what I asked.
Unfortunately Linux is starting to suffer from Weinberg's "White Bread Recipe Warning" and attracting the Windows "use Excel and Access for everything" crowd.

Answer (score 47):

This question is currently one of the top google results for "lightweight web server ubuntu", and while I didn't find the current answers all that helpful, I stumbled upon another solution that is installed by default on most every linux system:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

This will run a webserver in the current directory (html, css, images, documents, etc), serving the files to `localhost:8000`, and shouldn't require any additional software installation. [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) for this module has more information on parameters, etc.

For someone looking to quickly test a website, this is an ideal solution.

Comment: it's worth noting that the Python 3 equivalent would be `python3 -m http.server`.

Comment: worth adding that you can pass the port with, for eample `python3 -m http.server 80` to set the server to listen to port 80

Answer (score 3):

If you have PHP installed then you can use it's built-in webserver to quickly serve a directory.

```
cd www/
php -S localhost:1234
```

and your `www/` directory is now available at `http://localhost:1234/`

Answer (score 2):

I used Mongoose (SHTTPD) for some quick testing. I needed to test HTTP/S + CGI on the fly and found it rather easy to use. I did come across one problem. Whenever I pushed the process into the background the CGI pages would stop working. This was fixed by issuing:

```
nohup <command> &
```

Anyways, the link for Mongoose is http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/ if you're interested. For such a tiny web server the features are pretty good.

> - Crossplatform - works on Windows, MacOS and most flavors of UNIX
>
>   - CGI, SSL, SSI, Digest (MD5) authorization, resumed download, aliases
>   - IP-based ACL, Windows service, GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE methods
>   - Small footprint: 40 Kb executable on Linux 2.6 i386 system
>   - Embeddable with simple and clean API. Source is in single .c file to make things easy
>   - Language suport for:
>         o C/C++ (native)
>         o Python - since version 2.6 (done)
>         o C# - since version 2.7 (done)
>         o Ruby - since version 2.9 (todo)
>         o Lua - since version 2.9 (todo)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is one of the several LAMP available on Linux, and it is a good one.

Installation is easy (documentation is [here](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#374)): load the archive and then:

> sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.3a.tar.gz -C /opt
>
> cd /opt/lampp/
>
> sudo ./lampp start

Furthemore it does not clash with the filesystem (the full archive is dezipped in /opt directory).

Please look at the full list of [X-AMP distributions in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMP_packages).

Comment: Xampp is HORRILBE and takes 2 more commands than tasksel to install,  and cannot be updated easily.

Comment: Yes it takes 2 more commands than tasksel but you can write a script. Furthermore it can be updated very easily (remove, download, unzip, restart) and I don't understand why you want to "up-to-date" with a LAMP distribution for development.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is awesome,  it has a much easier AMP install than Windows(using xampp). Just run this:

```
sudo tasksel
```

Check "LAMP" and it will install the entire stack for you. I also recommend doing a :

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Just go to http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin to setup new databases.

Comment: LAMP is great but did you read what the OP wrote: a *lightweight Web server* similar to Web Savant.

Comment: Apache is extremely light weight compared to IIS.   Its all relative, Apache will fill his needs.

Comment: he didn't say IIS, he said Web Savant. they are *not* the same thing.

Comment: thttpd is too way heavy,  use netcat.

Comment: which doesn't support cgi. the op said *easy to use* not "well nigh impossible"

Answer (score 0):

I also use the Python approach mentioned here by @sAlexander, but at times need to have the server listening on something other than `localhost`. In my case, I'm testing Android apps running in an Android VirtualBox VM.  By default, these virtual Android devices are connected to the VirtualBox host-only adapter at 192.168.56.xx, so the server address needs to be 192.168.56.1.  To do this, I use the following python script which I adapted from a Linux Journal [tech tip](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python):

```
import sys
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

HandlerClass = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
ServerClass  = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
Protocol     = "HTTP/1.0"

if sys.argv[1:]:
    server = sys.argv[1]
else:
    server = '127.0.0.1'

if sys.argv[2:]:
    port = int(sys.argv[2])
else:
    port = 8000

server_address = (server, port)

HandlerClass.protocol_version = Protocol
httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)

print "httpd on", server, ":", port

httpd.serve_forever()
```

Arguments are server address (1st argument) and port (2nd), with defaults of 127.0.0.1 (`localhost`) and 8000, respectively. You can specify neither, just an address, or both address and port.

Answer (score -1):

xampp? http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: This is an UBUNTU system,  XAMPP  is difficult to install and update compared to apt.

Comment: I don't agree: you just need to unpack xampp in /op directory and starts it with sudo command. As it is isolated from the ubuntu filesystem, it doesn't clash with it.

Comment: well, then:
`sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin` and you're good to go =) I never used xampp before, tho...

Comment: Personnaly, i don't like to have the webserver and all its friend (mysql, etc...) started every time I boot my ubuntu. Well, it's just a matter of opinion...

Comment: I am always hacking away on some code, so I always want 'em up :)

Comment: xampp is horrible,  i would never use it.  It can't be updated and has a terrible security record.