# Firefox HTTP resource test post parameter

Tags: firefox, post, httpwebrequest

I'm using HTTP Resource Test on Firefox and want to simulate a POST request. However I didn't find where to write the post parameters. There are only URI, Representation and Headers, is there any way that I can pass with some post parameter? (In Json format?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload of the post should go in the body of the request. It's shown here:

https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/previews/full/54/54035.png?modified=1297743921

For example, if you were posting a JSON document you could just paste the JSON in the "Body" text area.

Comment: I see a 'Body' text area for the server response (containing 'Life, the Universe, and Everything') but that can't be correct re: original question?

Answer (score 0):

The payload of the post should go in 'Client Request' / 'Representation'.

It's shown [on this screenshot](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/previews/full/54/54034.png?modified=1297743921).

As an aside, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770981/12704) describes an excellent test server to use as a sanity-check.