# Such thing as a dummy REST server to test HTTP requests?

Tags: http, testing, web

I have been searching around but cannot find any site like this. I want to know if there is some dummy server that will respond to test GET requests and return a JSON object? Basically something like:

```
HTTPUtil.httpGet("http://www.ipsumlorem.com/json");
```

and have it return filler text JSON objects like:

```
{
   "title" : "Ipsum Lorem",
   "content" : "blah blah blah"
}
```

Comment: if this doesn't exist, then I am going to create one right now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Test server that accepts GET/Post calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-that-accepts-get-post-calls)

Comment: 50 lines of python gets you an HTTP server that can serve anything you want whether that is HTTP GET/HEAD/POST etc etc
 https://gist.github.com/trevorboydsmith/d88af55590784f88adb61227d33d8b4e

Comment: Or try fakedata.dev which lets you access a million fake user accounts.

Comment: You can use online mock api tools like themockapis.in

Answer (score 35, accepted):

http://www.jsontest.com/ will be your new best friend I guess...

Try this out for your need: http://echo.jsontest.com/title/ipsum/content/blah

It will return this:

```
{
   "content": "blah",
   "title": "ipsum"
}
```

Comment: this url frequently responds that its exceeded its max requests.  the code is available on git hub.  i've downloaded it but cannot tell if its an eclipse project or a netbeans project or if it can be complied at the command line.  does anyone know?

Answer (score 14):

You can use also [www.mocky.io](http://www.mocky.io/), where you mock your HTTP responses to test your REST API.

It is possible to change also the headers of the response and of course to write precisely the content (including json...)

Answer (score 10):

For following tutorials and giving workshops this could be useful as well:
[http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use http://apiary.io to create mock REST APIs very quickly.

If you don't care about the Content-Type it is even faster if you put a plain text file in Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SoftwareMill's TestServer: https://github.com/softwaremill/softwaremill-common/tree/master/softwaremill-test/softwaremill-test-server