# HTTP rest test service?

Tags: http, rest, post

I want to know what are the best options out there to test for example a POST request?

So am developing a client app and I want to send POST requests to see if the HTTP layer is working fine but I don't have a server I can hit with those POST requests.

What options are available out there?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Such thing as a dummy REST server to test HTTP requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734211/such-thing-as-a-dummy-rest-server-to-test-http-requests)

Comment: @Eric: So I think you're right. However... that question has no accepted answer. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried the URIs in the answers? Just because nothing is accepted doesn't mean the answers won't help you. If you're okay with JSON, then jsontest.com certainly seems reasonable.

Comment: @eric: so, I did look at those uris but didn't get much luck. For example the one that seemed the option I was going for was the one suggested by Laurent Bristiel, but I am not sure how to test POSTs. The example he gives is this:  http://echo.jsontest.com/title/ipsum/content/blah, but I want to send data through the body not in the url... so, I am not sure how to do that still. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Test server that accepts GET/Post calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-that-accepts-get-post-calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few awesome tools I **must** share

**For testing REST client**

http://requestb.in/

http://httpbin.org/

**For testing web service**

to quickly expose your local web service to web

[localtunnel](http://localtunnel.me/)

To test REST API

[Postman REST Client for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)

To intercept and inspect requests / response

[Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For chrome 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

and for mozillA

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/

You can sent Content Type and then You can use any method get, post , head, put , delete

Comment: these are client tools. I am looking for a server that can accepts any post request, so from my client I can send post requests and the server would respond accordingly....