# Google Apps Script: UrlFetchApp Post File

Tags: google-apps-script, http-headers

I'm trying to POST a file to a REST API via Google Apps Script. The idea is that I have a process that is creating copies of a Google Doc, and I want to be able to post those newly created Docs to a third party system.

I found in `UrlFetchApp` that I can send files. However, I'm having issues sending the correct header values.

My request looks like so:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
var body = {
  "file": file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)
};
var headers = {
  'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="'+ file.getName() +'"',
  'Content-Length': file.getSize()
};
```

My options when I call UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options) looks like :

```
({
  method:"POST", 
  headers:{
      'Content-Disposition':"attachment; filename=\"My Merge Development_row_1.pdf\"", 
      'Content-Length':90665, 
       Authorization:"Bearer TOKEN"
  }, 
  contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
  muteHttpExceptions:true, 
  payload:{file:Blob}
})
```

The API that I'm sending the files to requires the `'Content-Length'` header. But, when I try to set a value for `'Content-Length'` header I get an Apps Script error, `"Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:Content-Length"`. If I don't set the `Content-Length` header then the API responds that the `Content-Length` and file size don't match.

Any ideas on how I set the `Content-Length` header so I can POST the file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an [existing ticket highlighting that the documentation is not clear on this very issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2384)

The solution is:

> Move content length value from "content-Length" name/value pair in
>   headers to the advanced argument "contentLength"

So in your example your options should look like

```
({
  method:"POST", 
  headers:{
      'Content-Disposition':"attachment; filename=\"My Merge Development_row_1.pdf\"", 
       Authorization:"Bearer TOKEN"
  }, 
  contentLength: 90665,
  contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
  muteHttpExceptions:true, 
  payload:{file:Blob}
})
```

EDIT: Added a full example function to get contentLength and blob shown below:

```
function testFilePost() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc_id).getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var headers = {
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="'+ file.getName() +'"',
  };
  var options =
      {
        "method" : "post",
        "payload": file.getBytes(),
        "headers": headers,
        "contentLength": file.getBytes().length,
      };
  var result = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://httpbin.org/post', options).getContentText());
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @mhawksey! I made this change, and starred the issue. The change got me passed the Google Apps Script error, however the API now doesn't see the value being sent. I'm still getting the message that the Content-Length doesn't match the file length. I'm now trying to see what is actually being sent by UrlFetchApp, but I'm not seeing the request when inspecting Network traffic in Google Dev Tools. Is there some place else I can see the POST being sent by UrlFetchApp?

Comment: Swapping out your service endpoint with httpbin should work (See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9770981/1027723)

Comment: Cool! httpbin is quite helpful! According to my output from httpbin my header value for Content-Length: 60. Although, my options.fileLength = 90665. Any ideas what could cause these two to be different?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a sample function which gets the Google Doc as pdf and calcs content-length

Comment: Thank you, @mhawksey! The updated example was awesome. It turns out I also needed to set my Content-Type to 'application/pdf'. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Cool. Thanks for noting the Content-Type