# Put request via urlfetchapp produces "Exception: Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:Content-Length"

Tags: exception, google-apps-script, urlfetch

Goal is to update "OrderStatusID" of order to "1" using urlfetchapp with a put request via Apps Script.

```
function updateOrderStatus(){

  var private_key = "{private_key}";
  var merchant_token = "{merchant_token}";
  var secure_url = "{secure_url}";
  
  var body = JSON.stringify({"OrderStatusID": "1"});
  var url ="https://apirest.3dcart.com/3dCartWebAPI/v2/Orders/{orderID}";
  
  var options =  {
    "method" : "put",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "Content-Length" : body.length,
      "Accept" : 'application/json',
      "SecureURL" : secure_url,
      "PrivateKey" : private_key,
      "Token" : merchant_token
    },
    "body" : body,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : false,
  }
  try{
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  }
  catch(err){
    Logger.log(err);
  }
  finally{
    Logger.log(response);
  }
}
```

Code throws error Exception: Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:Content-Length

Code altered to remove sensitive information.

Comment: hm, is `body` the same as you presented in the example? Has been a while since I've done GAS thoroughly, but the code looks ok to me if the stringified body consists of single-octet chars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26615965

Comment: @Aerials that leads to the proper answer.  Content-Length calculates automatically.  All I needed to do was remove that header and change "body" to "payload" and the code worked fine.  Thank you for helping point me in the right direction.

Comment: @GaryD I'm glad it helped you. Would you like to post an answer to this question?

Comment: @Aerials, I added an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the name of the option "body" to "payload" resolved the issue.

The answer was found in this [google issue tracker thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36755661).

> ek...@googlers.comek...@googlers.com #6Apr 11, 2016 07:03AM Status:
> Won't Fix (Not Reproducible) UrlFetchApp doesn't have an advanced
> parameter called 'contentLength'. The Content-Length header is
> automatically calculated based on the length of the payload passed in.
> The 'contentLength' advanced parameter you set in your sample is
> simply ignored by the backend and the length automatically calculated.

The Content-Length is automatically calculated from the payload.  I thought it was supposed to be named body because the [3dCart API](https://apirest.3dcart.com/v2/orders/index.html#update-a-specific-order-by-id) documentation was using body as the name of its json in the example.

Corrected Code:

```
function updateOrderStatus(){

  var private_key = "{private_key}";
  var merchant_token = "{merchant_token}";
  var secure_url = "{secure_url}";
  
  var body = JSON.stringify({"OrderStatusID": "1"});
  var url ="https://apirest.3dcart.com/3dCartWebAPI/v2/Orders/{orderID}";
  
  var options =  {
    "method" : "put",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      //"Content-Length" : body.length,
      "Accept" : 'application/json',
      "SecureURL" : secure_url,
      "PrivateKey" : private_key,
      "Token" : merchant_token
    },
    "payload" : body,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : false,
  }
  try{
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  }
  catch(err){
    Logger.log(err);
  }
  finally{
    Logger.log(response);
  }
}
```