# Website with Echo Service

Tags: tcp, server, client, echo

For an assignment, I was asked to write a client that would use the echo service provided by a website. However, I don't know of any websites that I can use to test my code out with. Do you guys have any suggestions? I am coding in C++ in Visual Studio, if it's of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer.  It doesn't get any better than the site this SO user created:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770981/3299157 
The site he created is: 
http://httpbin.org/