# Error in receiving httpget respponse

Tags: http, gsm

I am using GSM module (M95 Quectel). As per given example of `Send HTTP GET Request` in Quectel http command manual, I am sending the command but in the end I failed to get a response from the server side. Its show the following error when sending:

```
send AT+QHTTPGET
+CME ERROR 3827
```

How can I get the correct response and read the data?

Answer (score 0):

The QHTTPGET command should be sent with the to_read_time variable. for example:
AT+QHTTPGET=60 please check if this is what you are doing.
In addition, you can check the URL you are trying to perform the GET request to in chrome, by entering it and view the response to check server validity.
Also, you can try checking if you mannage to perform a GET request to a test server such as in here:
[HTTP Test server that accepts GET/Post calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-that-accepts-get-post-calls)