# Slow website/server for testing HTTP modules

Tags: http, testing

I was working on an application with http client and it even included some use cases with involving requests through proxy, was actually in lookout for a website which responds slow. Found one nice utility which someone developed and sharing here as it might help others who end in same boat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website is http://fake-response.appspot.com

Ref: http://www.seanshadmand.com/2012/06/21/fake-response-server-slow-response-time-generator/

It even has a specific preconfigured data to respond with etc, but I did not explore much.

One more: http://httpbin.org/
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770981

Httpbin is awesome that it works as a http request mirror which provides all the request information like headers, cookies, ip, user agent, redirects, dummy content in html, xml, images etc, auth support, setting cookies and lot more.

Comment: fake-response has been down for some time. Here's a service that works as of now and can mock slow service responses: https://flash-the-slow-api.herokuapp.com/. Also, an example of a httpbin API to simulate slow responses (say 10 seconds) is: GET https://httpbin.org/delay/10

Comment: there is also https://httpbin.org/drip?duration=30&numbytes=30&delay=0