# Angularjs2 Post method to asp.net core passes empty object

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

recently I started learning Angular2 and Asp.net core, ran in to an issue to post an object here is my code:

`Service.ts` file:

```
export class SubCategoryService {
//private headers: Headers;
constructor(private http: Http) {
    //this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
   // this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   // this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
}
public createItem = (subCategory: SubCategory): Observable<SubCategory> =>
{
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let toAdd = JSON.stringify(subCategory);
    return this.http.post("api/subcategory", toAdd, { headers: headers }).map((response: Response) => <SubCategory>response.json()).catch(this.handleError);        

}
}
```

`Component.ts` file:

```
export class SubCategoryComponent {
constructor(private service: SubCategoryService) { }
subCategories: SubCategory[];
SubCategory: SubCategory = new SubCategory();
onPost() {
    this.service.createItem(this.SubCategory).subscribe(
        subCategory => this.subCategories.push(subCategory),
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log('Get all items completed'));
    this.isLoading = true;

}
}
```

Asp.Net Core `Controller`

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Post(SubCategory subCategory)
    {
        return new JsonResult("");
    }
```

It hits my controller with empty objec... Please any help would be appreciated.

Also tried with a postman to post it works just fine, maybe is something wrong with the information in a body?

Here is a screenshot with which it does work:

[image]

Comment: Try using an echo service like requestb.in or these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-that-accepts-get-post-calls

Comment: And I just saw this one today that I want to try: https://echo.getpostman.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are POSTing to the server in a wrong format.

Your postman request hints that your server is expecting `x-www-form-urlencoded` format, which is something like this:

```
Id=5&Name=Test
```

And your Angular application is sending something like this:

```
{"Id":5,"Name":"Test"}
```

So either you ditch `JSON.stringify` in your client-side method and construct the form data the query way (as well as set the `Content-Type` to `x-www-form-urlencoded`), or add `FromBodyAttribute` to your back-end action:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Post([FromBody]SubCategory subCategory)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :) Just added a `[FromBody]` attribute to controller action and left `new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })`