# Why does Swagger Editor show "undefined" headers for an operation with a custom header?

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm using the online Swagger Editor (http://editor.swagger.io) and the `heroku-pets.yaml` example. I changed the `GET /` operation to introduce a custom header `token`:

```
paths:
  /:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: limit
          in: query
          description: number of pets to return
          type: integer
          default: 11
          minimum: 11
          maximum: 10000
        - name: token
          in: header
          description: token
          type: string
```

But when I do "Try it out", there's an error "ERROR Server not found or an error occurred", and the "Headers" say `undefined`.

[image: Code manipulated for testing purpose]

Any idea what might be wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Requests sent directly from the browser via Ajax are subject to the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (cross-origin request sharing) rules. As part of that, the target server can specify which HTTP headers are allowed in a request. In your case, the target host `petstore-api.herokuapp.com` only allows the `Content-Type` header for requests to `/pet`, which can be seen by doing a [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) OPTIONS request:

```
> curl -X OPTIONS http://petstore-api.herokuapp.com/pet

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type     <-------------
Allow: GET,POST,PUT,GET
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
```

That's why you get the error when trying to use a custom header.

To test custom headers, you'll need a [test server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725430/113116) that can accept custom headers. One such server is the awesome http://httpbin.org which will echo the data sent in the request. So you could use something like this:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: test
  version: '1.0'
host: httpbin.org
schemes: [http, https]
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /get:
    get:
      summary: Returns GET data
      parameters:
        - name: token
          in: header
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```

Comment: Thanks Helen!. Could you please provide me an example where header and query params as are passed as request and getting array of object as       response. Right know i hv implemented the above said scenario and i am getting 404 error during preflight.