# can you escape the equals sign in POST data

Tags: post, urlencode

I ran into this POST form [example](https://github.com/kemalcr/kemal/issues/257), which sends some `application/x-www-form-urlencoded.` data:

```
 curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/bla -X POST --data 'x%3D1'
```

Should a server interpret that as a form name value pair "x=1" or as "x%3D1=[empty]"?  Can you escape the equals sign in the encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I put it through every test server I could find:

[HTTP test server accepting GET/POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-accepting-get-post-requests)

and all of them treat `x%3D1` as "a long key named 'x=1', with no value" and not equivalent to "x=1" (the key value pair) so I'm going to say it's not allowed, at least by de facto allowance :)