# Could someone give me a url that uses POST method?

Tags: http

I am writing a http proxy and I need to test if it can handle POST requests, but I can not find a URL that uses POST method.

Could someone give me one?

Thanks.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-accepting-get-post-requests it should have what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: `http://ptsv2.com/`

Read the instructions on the page. To help you further, I suggest that you use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), (it doesn't answer requests but is a great tool to help you compose your requests)

*Also you need to show that you've done some research first. Or your question will get downvoted to hell.*